# What happens to a troll that is perfectly vertically bisected by a normal weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, regeneration

The title pretty much covers it. For reference, see http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/troll.htm and http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#regeneration

There is, of course, no definitive answer in the rulebooks on this. However if you know of some relevant ruling by the game developers that has been published, that would be useful. I'm also interested to hear your personal interpretations.

Comment: I'm not sure this question can be answered. The [tour] says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced". However, you're never going to perfectly cut a troll in half, not down to the last atom (unless there's a spell in 3.5e that does that, I'm definitely no 3.5e expert. Wish could probably do it?). Regardless, even if you can perfectly cut a troll in half, the only reasonable answer I can imagine to this question would be "it's up to the DM". Thus, I'm voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: That being said, while you're not technically "new", welcome back to the site regardless! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I don't see how the bisection could ever truly be "perfect" without the use of *Wish*.  "Perfect" is a pretty tall order.  Perfect down to the quantum level?

Comment: The obvious answer is that they will begin to suffer from a split personality ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That and probably a splitting headache